# Get all nested resources records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have to following model

```
User
has_many :threads
....

Thread
belongs_to :user
has_many :posts
....    

Post
belongs_to :thread
....
```

To get all Threads from a user i can just `User.find( params[:id]).threads`
How can i get all posts from a user ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class User
  has_many :threads
  has_many :posts, :through => :threads
end
```

User.find(params[:id]).posts

should do the trick unless I'm dain-bramaged this morning.

Answer (score 2):

```
User
has_many :threads
has_many :posts, :through => :threads
....

Thread
belongs_to :user
has_many :posts
....    

Post
belongs_to :thread
```

Then you should be able to do:

```
user = User.first
user.posts
```